# R inner join has more rows than in the first frame

Tags: r, inner-join

With inner join the number of lines cannot be higher than in the 1st data frame. But why does R output a higher number of rows?

I have measured values in the 1st data frame and would like to supplement these data frames with unique information from a second data frame.
For example: the 1st data frame has 368000 lines, the second data frame has 19870 unique values.

```
Data<-tidyft::left_join(data_measurement_document, measurement points, by = "T1")
```

But this returns 968497 values! That cannot be. I only have 368000 measured values!

From my point of view, there must not be more lines than in the first data frame.

```
Data<-tidyft::inner_join(data_measurement_document, measurement points, by = "T1")
```

How can I get the various join functions in R to generate only the maximum number of lines of the first data frame?

Note:

- measurement points: This has **unique values in T1**, no duplicate values occur.
- data_measurement_document: Here the values of **T1 are not unique**.
- There must not be more rows in the result than in the dataset: data_measurement_document.

[Example data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTlkx.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQaoY.png)

Comment: You mention an inner join but your code uses a left join, which will produce larger output wherever there is a one-to-many relationship between keys. It sounds like you meant to use `inner_join` instead.  https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html

Comment: @JonSpring Even an `inner_join` can produce larger output, if the same key appears multiple times in both datasets.

Comment: @ elkalamaras : There must not be more rows in the results than in the data set: data_measurement_document

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & sometimes limited to titles, but read the help. Google re googling/searching, including in Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 2):

Check if there are duplicate values of variable "T1" in your data.

If there are duplicates values in the second table in the column you are joining by then this behaviour would be expected. `left_join` will join each occurrence in the first table with each occurrence in the second table. Consider the following example. (I'm using `left_join` from `dplyr` instead of `tidyft` but I assume the functions behave similarly.)

```
data1 <- data.frame(id=1:3,
                value1=paste0('data1_value',1:3),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1),
                    value2=paste0('data2_value',1:2),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

data3 <- left_join(data1,data2)
```

Then `data1` has 3 rows

| id | value1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | data1_value1 |
| 2 | data1_value2 |
| 3 | data1_value3 |

`data2` has 2 rows, but the `id` value is duplicated

| id | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | data2_value1 |
| 1 | data2_value2 |

And `data3`, the left-joined data, has 4 rows

| id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | data1_value1 | data2_value1 |
| 1 | data1_value1 | data2_value2 |
| 2 | data1_value2 | NA |
| 3 | data1_value3 | NA |

because the row id=1 in data1 gets joined with the 2 rows in table2 with id=1.

### Edit

I have used your sample data and `inner_join` in the code below but it does not produce more rows that there were in the first table

```
data1 <- structure(list(T1 = c(115, 160, 150, 115, 116, 150), 
                        Value.1 = c("A",  "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

data2 <- structure(list(T1 = c(115, 116, 150, 160), 
                        Value.2 = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

data3 <- inner_join(data1,data2,by="T1")
```

The result (data3) is below:

| T1 | Value.1 | Value.2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 115 | A | X1 |
| 160 | B | X4 |
| 150 | C | X3 |
| 115 | D | X1 |
| 116 | E | X2 |
| 150 | F | X3 |

This is the same number of rows as the left data frame.

Comment: Hello shaun_m,
Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I made a mistake in the post. I mean the inner_joint:

Data<-tidyft::inner_join(data_measurement_document, measurement points, by = "T1")

Hint:
measurement points: has unique values in T1, no duplicate values occur

data_measurement_document: Here the values of T1 are not unique.

Comment: Hi Freidbert. I have updated my answer using the sample data added to the question. I do not get more records than the first table contained. Could you post the results that you got from running your code on your sample data?

Comment: Hi shaun,
your example works for me too!
I have now loaded my data into test code and the results are plausible. I will look into the cause and get back to you.